# Read the contents of a modified buffer in Vim

Tags: vim, buffer

How can I access the contents of a modified buffer in Vim?

For example, if I want to concatenate the contents to a temporary file, like:

```
:! cat % > /tmp/modified.txt
```

But that gives me the last saved contents of the file (rightly so?). I do want to avoid saving the file before because this interaction is *meant* to allow some analysis without saving the buffer first.

It seems that the Python extension for Vim allows you to do something like:

```
def buffer_contents(buffer=vim.current.buffer):
    contents = buffer[:]
```

But I can't find any `VimL` references for the same functionality.

EDIT: It seems I could do something like:

```
:let buffer_contents = join(getline(1, '$'), '$')
```

At this point I just wonder if there is a builtin approach.

Comment: Why do you need `join()` in the last command? `getline(1, '$')` will get you the list of lines in a buffer and there is nothing more builtin than this. By the way, don’t use `buffer=vim.current.buffer`, default arguments are computed only once at function creation hence if you switch buffers it will point to the wrong one.

Comment: I was just trying to give an example, not correct Python :). I used join because I don't want an array. Nothing thought that should be inconvenient to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append current contents to temporary file you can use

```
:w! >> /tmp/modified.txt
```

,

```
:w! > /tmp/modified.txt
```

for overwriting that file (like in your cat example). To pass it to stdin of some script

```
:w !some-script
```

. Wondering though what’s wrong with your `getline(1, '$')`?

Comment: This solution still saves to the file, I am asking *not* to save before doing this. There is nothing wrong with my approach, I just wanted to know if there is a builtin that I am just not aware of.

Comment: @alfredodeza `w !some-script` does not save to a file. By the way, if you can possibly have any sequence of characters in a file (including zero bytes) you have no other option then using lists or python: VimL strings can’t contain these bytes so they are represented as newlines taking out the only line separator which is guaranteed not to be present in the string.

Comment: I did not know that `:w !some-script` would not save to a file, let me try that!

Comment: @alfredodeza It may save to a file on some systems where pipes are not available or if `shelltemp` option is set (it is by default in nocompatible mode, I override it in vimrc, you can use usual `let savedstmp=&shelltemp | set noshelltemp | try | execute 'w !some-script' | finally | let &shelltemp=savedstmp | endtry`). But this is done in background. Very unsure what is the background of the decision to set shelltemp by default in nocompatible mode. According to the documentation files will be used in any case if using pipes is not possible, so this code is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use `getline(1, $)` to retrieve all (modified) lines in the buffer, when your goal is writing them to a file, the `:w! > filename` as per ZyX's answer is still the way to go. Though there is a `writefile()` function in Vimscript, you'd have to deal with encodings, line endings, etc. all on your own, and that's simply too cumbersome when the built-in `:write` can do it for you.